# Как заставить flex-элемент ужиматься под родителя?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть ***flex-контейнер***, внутри **2** элемента расположенные по центру и вертикально с фиксированной шириной.

Вопрос: как заставить их ужиматься под ширину родителя при уменьшении его ширины.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
}

.flex {
  width: 250px;
}

.flex1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.flex2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex flex1">1 блок</div>
  <div class="flex flex2">2 блок</div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/staroverr/3txb4c5n/14/)

Если оставить внутри один блок, а родителю задать `flex-direction: row` и `justify-content: center` будет работать так, как нужно - [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/staroverr/3txb4c5n/18/), но **нужно 2 элемента внутри**

Comment: `.flex { max-width: 250px; }` вместо `.flex { width: 250px; }`, не?

Comment: вроде то, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы блоки не схлопывались, при малой ширине или отсутствии контента, пытаемся растянуть их на всю ширину родителя:

```css
width: 100%; /* Устанавливаем и забываем (см. далее) */
```

Одновременно ограничиваем блокам максимальную ширину:

```css
max-width: 250px; /* Теперь за начальную ширину блока отвечает это свойство */
```

Таким образом добиваемся "резиновости" блока. Т.е. блок имеет нужную нам ширину, но может уменьшаться при необходимости:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  /* для интерактивности */
  resize: both; overflow: hidden; outline: 1px dashed #666;
}


/* .flex { width: 250px; } */

.flex {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  
  min-width: 10ch;
  padding: .5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex1 { background-color: green; }
.flex2 { background-color: blue; }
.flex3 { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex flex1">1 блок</div>
  <div class="flex flex2">2 блок содержит больше текста</div>
  <div class="flex flex3">3 блок превышает максимальную установленную ширину, поэтому возникают переносы, но не растягивание блока</div>
</div>
```

Также желательно установить для блоков  `min-width` и `padding`, чтобы максимально сохранять читабельность, при сильном сжатии по ширине.

Comment: Хороший, полезный ответ, особенно для начинающих, которые могут его использовать для изучения CSS, благодаря подробным комментариям

Comment: Вот это именно то, что было нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае можно, как вариант, ширину для флекс элементов задать таким образом:

```
.flex {
      max-width: 250px;
      width: 100%;
      }
```

Тогда и начальная ширина в 250px сохранится и ужиматься под родителя будут.